# what is the correct format for inserting dates from text file using Teradata SQL Assistant

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to insert data from a tab delimited text file to a Teradata table i created.
It seems Teradata SQL Assistant does not recognize the dates in the file as dates

If I try the following code

```
create set table my_table
(
    update_date date
    , status_code smallint
)

INSERT INTO my_table 
VALUES (?, ?)
```

I recieve the error: Invalid value for update_date

However, when I try the code

```
create set table my_table
(
    update_date varchar(32)
    , status_code smallint
)

INSERT INTO my_table 
VALUES (?, ?)
```

The upload works smoothly.
I tried several formats: 28/08/2019, 2019-08-28 and also '2019-08-28'. All had yielded the same error

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but you could try explicitly casting the `DATE` values in your `CSV` file: `DATE '2019-08-28'`.  Maybe SQLA will pick it up that way.  Or maybe explicitly specify the format in your `DDL`: `update_date DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'`

Comment: @ravioli I have not tried to re-upload the data, however when doing a select: Cast (my_table.update_date AS DATE Format 'DD-MM-YYYY') worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Casting the value in the text file to a date by providing the correct format had solved the problem

The following code performs the required task with no errors:

```
create set table my_table
(
    update_date date
    , status_code smallint
)

insert into my_table 
values (cast (? as date format 'dd/mm/yyyy'), ?)
```

Comment: .. you comment is difficult to understand. Your solution does solve the error or is it a question? If its not a solutionn and the code creates an error... its a new question... Please clarify... your answer as it is currently flagged and examined under "low quality review". ( I do see you're OP of question.. so I guess its the solution? If so explain a bit more to rid it from review.

Comment: @ZF007 is it better now?